# Responsive Website both mobile and phone, mingle both Reactjs and React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, responsive

I want to the responsive web app on Mobile and Web page. I have built a website on React js. I have brought that website using a web view to React native and made it a mobile app. Now I need to direct my users depending upon the platform. If they are mobile users I need to direct them to React native app(live on the browser) and if they use the system they should be seeing the website I build. How can I do that? Is it possible? Suggest me a better Idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using your backend code by checking `request user agent` if you get mobile, you can redirect to some other url (Probably play store).

You can do the same via front end JS also (not advisable). You can use [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser) to detect if the user is on mobile, based on that redirect it to play store.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the navigator userAgent is mobile or not. If mobile add a links to your app or app store to download it.

```
if (/Mobi|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    // if I'm here that mean I'm a phone
}
```